# Service Bus Output Bindings Throwing Error in both Azure and Local Testing

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, servicebus

So I have the following function header:

```
 [FunctionName("listenServiceBus")]
        public static void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("metadataingest", AccessRights.Manage, Connection = "ServiceBus")]string mySbMsg,
        ExecutionContext context, [ServiceBus("successqueue", Connection = "DEVservicebus", EntityType = Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus.EntityType.Queue)]out string outputSuccess,
        [ServiceBus("failqueue", Connection = "DEVservicebus", EntityType = Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus.EntityType.Queue)]out string outputFailure, ILogger Log)
```

Where I bind to two separate Service Buses for input and outputs of the function. My function.json file looks like the following:

```
{
 "bindings": [
{
  "type": "serviceBusTrigger",
  "connection": "ServiceBus",
  "queueName": "metadataingest",
  "accessRights": "manage",
  "name": "mySbMsg"
},
{
  "name": "outputSuccess ",
  "type": "serviceBus",
  "queueName": "successqueue",
  "connection": "DEVservicebus",
  "direction": "out"
},
{
  "name": "outputFailure",
  "type": "serviceBus",
  "queueName": "failqueue",
  "connection": "DEVservicebus",
  "direction": "out"
}
  ],...
```

I am getting the following errors:

```
No job functions found. Try making your job classes and methods public. If 
you're using binding extensions (e.g. ServiceBus, Timers, etc.) make sure 
you've called the registration method for the extension(s) in your startup 
code (e.g. config.UseServiceBus(), config.UseTimers(), etc.).
```

And:

```
listenServiceBus: The binding name outputSuccess  is invalid. Please assign 
a valid name to the binding.
```

I am currently running .Net.Sdk.Function 1.0.12.Anyone know any workarounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See `"name": "outputSuccess ",` in your bindings, looks like there is an extra space after outputSuccess. You should delete it and try again.